# If cell text equals cell highlight background

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, background-color, conditional-formatting

[image: Q44840578 example]

I am trying to highlight the background of the off days, for each cell I am creating a separate custom formula rule containing:

```
=IF(TEXT(F6,"dddd")=H4)
```

just to test it out, but I am unable to get any results.

What am I missing?

Comment: `F6` is blank..

Comment: Try `=TEXT(F7,"dddd")=H4` only.

Comment: Why not use the WEEKDAY function?

Comment: @ProgSnob `WEEKDAY` will only return a number.

Comment: Yes, and you can also apply weekday on your OFF days and compare the numbers.  Much simpler.

Comment: @ProgSnob It would work if H4 is also in date format. But wouldn't if it is in general/text format.

Comment: Well appearantly I can't set cell rules from my iphone so I'll have to wait till I'm back at my PC, can't believe I didnt catch that I was on the wrong cell lol, I'll let you guys know :)

Comment: Well you know what weekday returns for Tuesdays and Wednesdays (4 and 5)- you can just use that.

Comment: Then have a VLOOKUP table with Days and values which the WEEKDAY function returns and compare it with the vlookup value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming G4 and H4 are text (formula would be simpler if a full date formatted as `dddd`) and that you want both off day columns formatted, please clear any existing CF from C8:I16, select C8:I16 and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=OR(LEFT(TEXT(C$7,"ddd"),2)=LEFT($G$4,2),LEFT(TEXT(C$7,"ddd"),2)=LEFT($H$4,2))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Note this will override formatting in Rows12:14 which will have to be reset even if applied with CF unless Applies to range for above is changed to:

```
=$C$8:$I$11,$C$15:$I$16
```

and existing CF formatting is not cleared first.

[OR](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/OR-function-7d17ad14-8700-4281-b308-00b131e22af0)
[LEFT](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/LEFT-LEFTB-functions-9203d2d2-7960-479b-84c6-1ea52b99640c)
[TEXT](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/TEXT-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c)

Comment: What exactly is LEFT saying?

Comment: I changed the orientation of the schedule, now instead of each day going across they go down, and the in, out, ect. are across the top.  I have modified the formula to reflect the proper cells, but now I cant get it to work =/

=OR(LEFT(TEXT(B$5,"ddd"),2)=LEFT($L$2,2),LEFT(TEXT(B$5,"ddd"),2)=LEFT($M$2,2))